# Python - How to convert circular or elliptical orbit data into a sine wave?

Tags: python-3.x, trigonometry, orbital-mechanics, sine-wave

I have a personal project I'd like to achieve as one of my first complete python projects/learning/experience. The project is to make an application that will accept some input (or just change hard-coded input) for a time scale, and convert planetary orbits into sound waves.

We would need to transpose the timescales up quite a bit to be able to hear an orbital frequency, and I want to be able to change that transposition depending on what the user or I want.

Let's say I pull Nasa JPL data, and they return something like this :

```
A.D. 2019-Jan-01 00:00:00.0000, -4.714853635016740E+07, -4.782573126195183E+07,  4.173036297464184E+05,
```

How can I take this Date, X, Y, Z information (there would be more information for many days, years etc... my/user choice) and convert it into a sine wave (probably into a CSV) where I can then take the CSV and generate a .wav using Python?

I believe I'll need to change the orbit information to exist within +1 and -1, and somehow figure out how to take the circular/elliptical data and convert it into sine waves (some X or Y data will need to invert from negative to positive? along an axis?)

Any help to get me on the right path would be greatly appreciated!